# How to check Not null value from Array in SQL

Tags: sql

I'm facing the problem while checking null value from array, I tried by adding the AND condition in where clause *"AND "txt" IS not null"* but it's not working.
Below is my query please help me out from this.

```
SELECT %s
       "module-id"    AS module_id,
       "per-num"      AS per_num,
       RTRIM ("txt"[1] || "txt"[2] || "txt"[3] || "txt"[4] || "txt"[5] ||
              "txt"[6] || "txt"[7] || "txt"[8] || "txt"[9] || "txt"[10])
                      AS note_text,
       "page-no"      AS page_number,
       "upd-dat"      AS updated_on,
       "upd-tim"      AS updated_time,
       "upd-usr-id"   AS updated_by,
       CASE WHEN "module-id" = 1 THEN 'Common'
            WHEN "module-id" = 5 THEN 'Rents'
            WHEN "module-id" = 8 THEN 'Arrears'
       END AS category
  FROM pub."perpad"
 WHERE "module-id" IN (1, 5, 8)
   AND ("per-num" > :perNumFrom
    OR ("per-num" = :perNumFrom AND "module-id" > :moduleIdFrom)
    OR ("per-num" = :perNumFrom AND "module-id" = :moduleIdFrom AND "page-no" >= :pageNumFrom))
   AND "upd-dat" >= :fromDate %s
```

```
AND "txt" IS not null
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please add your SQL implementation and version in the tags (Oracle 10g, 11g, 12c / Microsoft SQL Server 2016, 2017, 2019 / ...). Also, define "not working": do you receive an error, does the result not meet your expectation, etc. See [minimal, reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)